# Anaconda doesn't launch python program

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I have a program in a directory, which is started with a `Main.py` more or less as follows

```
import multiprocessing

def Procmatch(x):
   Do something

if __name__ == '__main__':

   print('Program has started')
   Do some thing

   p=multiprocessing.Process(target=Procmatch,args=(something,))
```

As I read, it can't be launched from inside the spyder IDLE because multi processes will stall, so I always launched it from the Anaconda Prompt.
Problem is that today that stopped working. 
I do as usual, I open the prompt, navigated with cd somewhere/somewhere to the directory and then

```
(base) C:\somewhere/project diretory> python3 Main.py start
```

Instead of laucnhing it, as it used to, it just do nothing, and I get another

```
(base) C:\somewhere/project diretory>
```

Not even the print that shows it has started. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happened, so I'll just answer my question.

The problem is that I don't have more than one version of python installed, meaning there is no need to make a difference between python3 and python2. If I just type `python Main.py start` it does work properly.

My bad, as I was using the command for the raspberry pi

On a side note, and always keeping on mind nobody has any obligation towards anybody, I'm finding the community here is less willing to help with each passing year. Might be my biased view, but that is what I'm seeing.